# Show that the characteristic of $R$ is $2$ and that $R$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity such that $r^2=r$ for all $r\in R$. Show that the characteristic of $R$ is $2$ and that $R$ is commutative.

My argument was the following. But, the thing I am not sure about is, whether we can say that $f$ has at most two roots in any ring.

So, let $f(x)=x^2-x\in R[x]$. Then $f$ has at most $2$ roots. $0,1\in R$ and they are roots of $f$. So, $R=\{0,1\}$. Hence Char $R=2$ and it is commutative.

Appreciate if point out any errors.

Comment: $R$ can have more than two elements. Consider $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, which has $2^n$ elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear that $f$ has at most two roots. For this you need that $R$ is a domain. For example, $p(x) = 2x \in \mathbb{Z}/4[x]$ has two roots.

Instead notice that for all $a \in R$
$$
  1+a
= (1+a)^2
= 1 + 2a + a^2
= 1 + 2a + a,
$$
so $2a = 0$. Therefore $\mathrm{char}(R) = 2$. For all $a,b \in R$ we now have
$$
  ab-ba
= ab+ba
= (a+b)^2 - a^2 - b^2
= a+b - a - b
= 0,
$$
so $R$ is also commutative.